# How to get the view count of taxonomy term pages in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm running Drupal 8.3. Statistics module can count views of a node. But is there a way to find out view count of taxonomy term pages?

I'm looking for how many times a taxonomy term page is viewed, but not the count of how many times a taxonomy term is used in nodes.

**Edit:**
In short, I'm looking for a similar module as below for Drupal 8.  https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_term_statistics

Comment: There is no such thing in Drupal. You will have to copy the logic for nodes and tailor it to terms. Have a look at statistics core module or entity_view_count or entity_statistics modules. Although they are only for D7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Drupal patch for Statistics module, which tracks view count for all content entities. It seems like this feature will be integrated into the core.

After applying the patch, I can track view counts for taxonomy term pages.

[image: Track view count of taxonomy term pages]

Link to the patch:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2532334